# ¿Cómo puedo escoger los 2 términos mayores en python?

Tags: python

Si tengo varias variables de tipo float y quiero escoger las 2 de mayor valor, ¿Cómo puedo hacer? En lenguaje Python

Comment: Que has intentado hasta ahora? Con gusto te daría una respuesta, pero primero es necesario que nos pruebes eres parte del proceso de encontrar una solución. Es una medida para evitar hacerle el ejercicio a alguien.

Comment: Por otro lado, te recomiendo que leas sobre la función [sorted](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted) la cual puede servir a tu proposito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes varias variables, ponlas en una lista:

```
variables = [1., 6., 3., 4., 5., 2.]
```

luego la ordenas usando `sorted`, que te devuelve la lista ordenada de menor a mayor, por lo que tomamos los dos últimos elementos:

```
print(sorted(variables)[-2:])
```

produce:

```
[5.0, 6.0]
```

Comment: También podías poner que se ordenen de mayor a menor y escoger las 2 primeras

Comment: @Christian. No es necesario.

Comment: eso solo en el caso de que no haya elementos repetidos.

Comment: Si siempre va a haber alguien que responda a aquellos que no han demostrado ningún esfuerzo, yo también voy a empezar a responder...

Comment: @DanteS. hice el mismo y planteo y la respuesta fue que en base a "suposiciones" se puede responder.

Comment: Si hay elementos repetidos, es decir, dos variables con el mismo flotante, puedes poner las variables en un set (en el cual si se ingresa un valor repetido, este no es ingresado). Es decir, el set `{5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}` es equivalente al set `{5,4,3,2,1}`.

Comment: es más simple usar lo ya contestado y mejorarlo : print(sorted(set(variables))[-2:])

Comment: @tincopasan en esa pregunta el OP afirmaba que hizo algo. En esta pregunta más bien es como si la persona hubiese leido el ejercicio y escribiera en la pregunta lo que entendió de este.

Comment: @DanteS.  afirmaba pero no mostraba! eso es  suponer que es cierto,

Comment: @tincopasan. Si hay valores repetidos no importa, el OP pide los dos mayores **elementos**. En ninguna parte se pide que sean distintos ...

Comment: @CandidMoe me imagino la utilidad de obtener de distintos valores dos iguales en este caso.